# Ignore Japanese Characters for ICU4J transliterations

Tags: java, cjk, transliteration, icu4j

Is there a way to ignore the all the Japanese characters for Transliteration using the ICU4J library?

What are the IDs of the transliterators that participate in the Japanese Transliteration?

The code to generate all the available transliterators is:

```
Enumeration<String> availableIDs = Transliterator.getAvailableIDs();
while (availableIDs.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(availableIDs.nextElement());
}
```

I am really interested in the first question to ignore the transliteration process for Japanese characters only and allow transliteration for rest of the characters(non-Japanese).